# mixitup and bootstrap .active class conflict

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to load a mixitup filter gallery on my bootstrap template.

Problem is when i'm loading the gallery on the first tab-pane that already active it works fine

but when i'm trying to load it under a the second or third tab-pane it doesn't work I think there's a conflict between the bootstrap .active class?

This is the main navigation menu for the tab panes

```
<div class="list-group">
   <a href="#landing" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="list-group-item active">Home<i class="pull-xs-right fa fa-home"></i></a>
   <a href="#about" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="list-group-item">About me <i class="pull-xs-right fa fa-star"></i></a>
   <a href="#services" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="list-group-item">What I do <i class="pull-xs-right fa fa-suitcase"></i></a>
   <a href="#portfolio" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="list-group-item">Portfolio <i class="pull-xs-right fa fa-photo"></i></a>
   <a href="#blog" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="list-group-item">Blog <i class="pull-xs-right fa fa-comment"></i></a>
   <a href="#contact" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="list-group-item">Contact <i class="pull-xs-right fa fa-phone"></i></a>
</div>
```

Here's the mixitup gallery

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="portfolio">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="filters">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="filter nav-link" data-filter=".plugins, .logo, .web">All</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="filter nav-link" data-filter=".plugins">App / Plugins</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="filter nav-link" data-filter=".logo">Logo Design</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="filter nav-link" data-filter=".web">Web Design</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://facebook.com/ydd.ninja" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">

    <div id="portfoliolist">

      <div class="portfolio logo" data-cat="logo">
        <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
          <img src="assets/images/bg.jpg" alt="" />
          <div class="label">
            <div class="label-text">
              <a href="#" class="text-title">Bird Document</a> 
              <span class="text-category">Logo</span>
            </div>
            <div class="label-bg"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="portfolio web" data-cat="web">
        <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
          <img src="assets/images/dp2.jpg" alt="" />
          <div class="label">
            <div class="label-text">
              <a href="#" class="text-title">Bird Document</a> 
              <span class="text-category">Web Design</span>
            </div>
            <div class="label-bg"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="portfolio plugins" data-cat="plugins">
        <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
          <img src="assets/images/1.jpg" alt="" />
          <div class="label">
            <div class="label-text">
              <a href="#" class="text-title">Bird Document</a> 
              <span class="text-category">App Design</span>
            </div>
            <div class="label-bg"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--//portfolio-list-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Code above will not work but if i make it as the active tab-pane on first load everything is fine all the portfolio navigation wont have problem and will be clickable and filter the gallery

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="portfolio">
```

Thanks in advance hope someone can help me with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution!

It was due to conflict with the bootstrap tab data-toggle that's why it wouldn't work.

Solution is the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
          var target = $(e.target).attr('href');
          if (target === '#portfolio') {
            if (!$('#portfoliolist').mixItUp('isLoaded')) {
              $('#portfoliolist').mixItUp({
                      selectors: {
                        target: '.portfolio',
                        filter: '.filter' 
                      },
                      load: {
                        filter: 'all' // show app tab on first load
                      }  

                    });   
            }
          }
        });

    });
```

Thanks to this dude in [mixitupforum](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/support/topic/filter-doesnt-work-with-bootstrap-3-tabs-modal/)

Comment: Can you please fix this on MixItUp v3.3.1 and Bootstrap v4.3.1 version?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the the filters/controls are inside the 'mixit' class container
and initiate the instance using this code.

```js
var mixer = mixitup('.mixit', {
         controls: {
          scope: 'local'
         }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Change, Work fine Try it:**

*specificly tell to filter to only action in **button.filter***

```
selectors: {
   control: 'button.filter'
}
```